# Spring boot web context (AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext)- suddenly being closed/shutdown

Tags: spring-mvc, springboard

I'm using **spring-boot 1.1.3** running a web application (obviously, based on spring-web, security and more) with an **embedded Tomcat**.

I'm running my application on **Linux (Ubuntu) machine** with **Java 1.7**.

After couple of hours, I can see that **the context is being closed without a reason**. Just to make it clear, the process didn't crash and is still running, when I try to post/get a request, the client just hangs.

I'm using **logback**, configure with debug level as **TRACE** and **I can not see who or why is close context is invoked.**
Can someone please tell me **how to detect the trigger for closing the context?**

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, the issue was not related directly to spring-boot but I wont change it's tag since other people might face the same scenario.
So, the unswer is the same for, How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?
just run your command with & at the end and than, execute disown.